# Block email addresses using Gmail API in Python

Tags: python, gmail-api

Is there anyway I could use the gmail API and block certain email addresses using a Python program? Searched around but couldn't find any documentation that could achieve this.

Comment: [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python)

Comment: The documentation has no direct option to block email addresses, but i have read that by moving an email to spam, future emails from that sender will be moved to spam as well, is this the only way?

Comment: That's how all filters working *(redirecting suspicious emails to spam folder)*. As far as I understood, API has methods to create filters so you could apply it.